# SignalR with React Problem - Websocket events doesn't work when navigating

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-router, signalr

I use ASP Web Api as a backend for my application, and React for Frontend with react router
we have a chat in some page that listens for new messages however
when I navigate to another chat room using react router the web socket receives the message
but doesn't update the chat component any more.

I was expecting that it will work without any problem, but it needs a refresh every time

Comment: We can't address issues in code we can't see. Can you [edit] the post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with? See also [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) for other guidance to improve the quality of your post to make it more answerable.